# Sqlite jquery nested loop

Tags: jquery, html, sqlite, loops, cordova

I'm a bit of an newbie in this  - I've been trying for a couple of days to modify various stackoverflow answers without any luck at all.

For my phonegap app - using sqlite, jquery I'm trying to loop through a category table, then have a nested list of 'kinds' for each category. The code below produces the outer loop, but not the inner.

Any help would be very much appreciated

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
     tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM cat;', [], function (transaction, catResult) {
          var theHtml ='';
          for (var i = 0; i < catResult.rows.length; i++) {
               // outer loop
                var catRow =catResult.rows.item(i);
               theHtml +='<li>' +catRow.Name;
               function doinner(i) {
                    var theHtml2 ='';
                    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM kind WHERE cat_id = ?;', [catRow.Id], function (transaction, kindResult) {
                         theHtml2 ='<ul>';
                         for (var i2 = 0; i2 < kindResult.rows.length; i2++) {
                              // inner loop
                               var kindRow =kindResult.rows.item(i2);
                              theHtml2 +='<li>' +kindRow.kind +'</li>';
                         };
                         // end inner loop
                          theHtml2 +='</ul>';
                    });
                    // end function
                     theHtml +=theHtml2;
               }
               // end doinner
               doinner(i) ;
                // this function is supposed to assemble and append the inner loop
                theHtml +='</li>';
          }
          // end outer loop
           $('#catList').html(theHtml);
     });
     // end function

});
 // end transaction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function you give to `executeSql` is executed asynchronously, so `theHtml2` does not yet contain anything when you are using it.

An easier way to handle this is to get the data with a single query with a join and then use a single loop to construct the HTML lists:

```js
tx.executeSql('SELECT cat.name, kind.kind ' +
              'FROM cat ' +
              'LEFT JOIN kind ON cat.id = kind.cat_id '+
              'ORDER BY 1, 2',
              [], function(tx, result) {
    var theHtml = '';
    var lastName = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = result.rows.items(i);
        if (row.name != lastName) {
            if (theHtml != '')
                theHtml += '</ul>';
            theHtml += '<li>' + row.name;
            lastName = row.name;
            theHtml += '<ul>';
        }
        if (!!row.kind)
            theHtml += '<li>' + row.kind + '</li>';
    }
    if (theHtml != '')
        theHtml += '</ul>';
    $('#catList').html(theHtml);
});
```

Comment: oh thanks, I'm a bit new to this could you  give me a clue how I would create the html as a nested list